# Proof to a matrix identity encountered in kernelized ridge regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

In deriving kernelized ridge regression I've encountered a matrix identity that I can't quite prove:

$$X^T(XX^T+\lambda I)^{-1}=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^T$$

Where $\lambda$ is a scalar constant and $X$ is assumed to be invertible.

I can see how this is true if the whole bracket is not an inverse itself, but after trying to apply some identities to expanding sum of inverses (namely, the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)), the whole thing just gets hopelessly complicated.

Can someone outline how this equality comes about?

The equation can be found on top of page 2 of [this paper](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/Kernel-Ridge.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiply by $(XX^T+\lambda I) $ on the right and by $(X^TX+\lambda I) $ on the left, your identity is
$$
(X^TX+\lambda I)X^T=X^T (XX^T+\lambda I),
$$
which is trivial to verify.

What you need is not that $X $ is invertible, but that $\lambda>0$; that guarantees that $X^TX+\lambda I $ and $XX^T+\lambda I $ are positive definite.